# Java client web server error file path not specified

Tags: java, webserver, client

I am getting the following error.

> [ERROR] .\client\CalculatorI.java (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)

While running wsdl file from cmd prompt I am getting this error.

> The wsdl file is created and it has been displayed.

I don't know how to change the path in jdk. I can't create the folder in `jdk/bin` as well.

Comment: Show us the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Please open wsdl file and take api url and check it's calling or not. if it's calling after that you can follow that link https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html

Comment: I got it resolved. I had to run the wsdl file from its path and had to include the path of the wsimport while running the wsdl file.